# How to parse part of .yaml file to object in SnakeYAML?

Tags: java, spring, snakeyaml

I have a yaml file, for example:

```yaml
# this is the part I don't care about
config:
  key-1: val-1
other-config:
  lang: en
  year: 1906
# below is the only part I care about
interesting-setup:
  port: 1234
  validation: false
  parts:
    - on-start: backup
      on-stop: say-goodbye
```

Also I have a POJO class that is suitable for the `interesting-setup` part

```java
public class InterestingSetup {
    int port;
    boolean validation;
    List<Map<String, String>> parts;
}
```

I want to load just the `interesting-setup` part (similarly as `@ConfigurationProperties("interesting-setup")` in Spring)

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```java
Map<String, Object> yamlConfig = yaml.load(yamlFile);            # loading the whole file to Map with Object values
Object interestingObject = yamlConfig.get("interesting-setup");  # loading 'interesting-setup' part as an object
Map<String, Object> interestingMap = (Map<String, Object>);      # Casting object to Map<String, Object>
String yamlDumped = yaml.dump(interestingMap);                   # Serialization to String
InterestingSetup finalObject = yaml.load(yamlDumped);            # Getting final object from String
```

The crucial part is when I have an Object (Map<String, Object>) and want to cast it to my final class.
To do that - I need to serialize it to String, so the process looks like this:

`File -> Map<String, Object> -> Object -> Map<String, Object> -> String -> FinalClass`
and I'd like to avoid deserialization and again serialization of the same data.

So can I somehow use `Yaml` to map the `Map<String, Object>` to another class? I cannot see this in an API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the SnakeYAML library doesn't provide a straight way to do that.

You may try tweaking it and defining a container base class with only the fields you required to support. Consider for example the following POJO:

```java
public class Container {
  private InterestingSetup interestingSetup;

  public InterestingSetup getInterestingSetup() {
    return interestingSetup;
  }

  public void setInterestingSetup(InterestingSetup interestingSetup) {
    this.interestingSetup = interestingSetup;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Container{" +
        "interestingSetup=" + interestingSetup +
        '}';
  }
}
```

Where, `InterestingSetup` is your own class:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class InterestingSetup {
  private int port;
  private boolean validation;
  private List<Map<String, String>> parts;

  public int getPort() {
    return port;
  }

  public void setPort(int port) {
    this.port = port;
  }

  public boolean isValidation() {
    return validation;
  }

  public void setValidation(boolean validation) {
    this.validation = validation;
  }

  public List<Map<String, String>> getParts() {
    return parts;
  }

  public void setParts(List<Map<String, String>> parts) {
    this.parts = parts;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "InterestingSetup{" +
        "port=" + port +
        ", validation=" + validation +
        ", parts=" + parts +
        '}';
  }
}
```

With those beans in place, the following code would work as you required:

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.TypeDescription;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String yamlString =
        "# this is the part I don't care about\n" +
        "config:\n" +
        "  key-1: val-1\n" +
        "other-config:\n" +
        "  lang: en\n" +
        "  year: 1906\n" +
        "# below is the only part I care about\n" +
        "interesting-setup:\n" +
        "  port: 1234\n" +
        "  validation: false\n" +
        "  parts:\n" +
        "    - on-start: backup\n" +
        "      on-stop: say-goodbye";

    // Skip unknown properties
    Representer representer = new Representer();
    representer.getPropertyUtils().setSkipMissingProperties(true);

    // Define the target object type
    Constructor constructor = new Constructor(Container.class);
    TypeDescription containerTypeDescription = new TypeDescription(Container.class);

    // Define how the interesting-setup property should be processed
    containerTypeDescription.substituteProperty("interesting-setup", InterestingSetup.class,
        "getInterestingSetup", "setInterestingSetup");
    constructor.addTypeDescription(containerTypeDescription);

    // Finally, parse the YAML
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor, representer);
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(yamlString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));;
    Container container = yaml.load(inputStream);
    System.out.println(container.getInterestingSetup());
  }
}
```

Perhaps, a more simple solution will consists on using some method that allows you, given a bunch of fields and their corresponding values, to set the appropriate information in the `InterestedSetup` bean. You can use the Reflection API for that. The [`populate` method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#populate-java.lang.Object-java.util.Map-) in the `BeansUtils` class from Apache Commons can also be handy as well:

```java
Map<String, Object> yamlConfig = yaml.load(yamlFile); 
Object interestingObject = yamlConfig.get("interesting-setup");
Map<String, Object> interestingMap = (Map<String, Object>);
InterestingSetup finalObject = BeanUtils.populate(interestingMap);
```

As an alternate approach, you can use Jackson to process the YAML file. The code will be similar to this:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
// As the helper object Container doesn't contain all the properties
// it is necessary to indicate that fact to the library to avoid
// errors
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
Container container = mapper.readValue(yamlString, Container.class);
System.out.println(container.getInterestingSetup());
```

The `Container` class is the same presented above with the addition of a `@JsonProperty` annotation in order to successfully handle the `interesting-setup` field:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

// Instead of mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
// you can annotate the class with @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
// to avoid errors related to unknown properties
public class Container {

  @JsonProperty("interesting-setup")
  private InterestingSetup interestingSetup;

  public InterestingSetup getInterestingSetup() {
    return interestingSetup;
  }

  public void setInterestingSetup(InterestingSetup interestingSetup) {
    this.interestingSetup = interestingSetup;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Container{" +
        "interestingSetup=" + interestingSetup +
        '}';
  }
}
```

The required artifacts can be downloaded from [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml) as the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Wrapping this in the Container class is very neat, thank you, you gave many possible solutions and this is very useful.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you very much @Benjamin. I am very happy to hear that the answer was helpful.